# How to Solve this Gradle error?

Tags: java, android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I got this error in Gradle Console

Error:A problem occurred configuring root project 'QuakeReport'.

> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':classpath'.
>   Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0.
>        Searched in the following locations:
>            file:/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/gradle/m2repository/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.0.0/gradle-3.0.0.pom
>            file:/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/gradle/m2repository/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.0.0/gradle-3.0.0.jar
>            https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.0.0/gradle-3.0.0.pom
>            https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.0.0/gradle-3.0.0.jar
>        Required by:
>            project :

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 41s

I got this error in messages

Error:A problem occurred configuring root project 'QuakeReport'.

> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':classpath'.
>   Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0.
>        Searched in the following locations:
>            file:/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/gradle/m2repository/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.0.0/gradle-3.0.0.pom
>            file:/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/gradle/m2repository/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.0.0/gradle-3.0.0.jar
>            https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.0.0/gradle-3.0.0.pom
>            https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.0.0/gradle-3.0.0.jar
>        Required by:
>            project :

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try adding this to your project level build.gradle.

```
  // Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: There are 2 which one ?

Comment: add both one in your allprojects and one in buildscript

Answer (score 0):

Android artifacts are no longer posted to bintray. Use google's repository to your build script.

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        ...
        // You need to add the following repository to download the
        // new plugin.
        google()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0'
    }
}
```

See here: https://developer.android.com/studio/build/gradle-plugin-3-0-0-migration.html#apply_plugin